# Display main TOC including entries with and without numerotation

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

Despite my efforts, I didn't find/understood the answer on the forum. Please forgive me if it's a duplicate.

I want to display the entire ToC using the titletoc package, including entries with and without numerotation. However, the code below display the main TOC only for entries with numerotation.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%Format titles , add Toc&minitoc
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

%Numbering to subsubsection
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\titlecontents{chapter}
[0pt]
{\bfseries\Large\addvspace{20pt}}
{\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel\space:\space}
{}
{\hfill\contentspage}

%Show subsubsection to numbered in TOC
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[english, french]{babel}
\begin{document}

    \title{My title}
    \author{My name}
    \tableofcontents        %Faire Table Of Content - TOC
        \setcounter{chapter}{0}
        \chapter*{Introduction}
        Blablabla       
        \chapter{Title of the chapter1 \label{chap1}}
        {\vspace*{1pc}\hrule\vspace*{1pc}}
        \startcontents[chapters]\vbox{\bf\Large}
        \printcontents[chapters]{}{-1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}}\vspace*{1pc}\hrule
        \newpage
        \section{Section1}
        Blablabla
        \subsection{subsection1}
        Blablabla
\end{document}
```

What did I miss?

Comment: It is a well known fact that unnumbered structure units are not added to the ToC....

Comment: Well that wasn't obvious for me, and not that straightforward when I looked for the answer on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling for a while, I simply got the answer from this discussion thread [https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=566][1].

I just added `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}` in the document environment, such as :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%Format titles , add Toc&minitoc
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

%Numbering to subsubsection
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\titlecontents{chapter}
[0pt]
{\bfseries\Large\addvspace{20pt}}
{\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel\space:\space}
{}
{\hfill\contentspage}

%Show subsubsection to numbered in TOC
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[english, french]{babel}
\begin{document}

\title{My title}
\author{My name}
\tableofcontents        %Faire Table Of Content - TOC
    \setcounter{chapter}{0}
    \chapter*{Introduction}
    Blablabla
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}       
    \chapter{Title of the chapter1 \label{chap1}}
    {\vspace*{1pc}\hrule\vspace*{1pc}}
    \startcontents[chapters]\vbox{\bf\Large}
    \printcontents[chapters]{}{-1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}}\vspace*{1pc}\hrule
    \newpage
    \section{Section1}
    Blablabla
    \subsection{subsection1}
    Blablabla
\end{document}
```

It actually add *manually* a chapter entry in the main TOC and display unnumbered entries.